# How to use es6 template literal as Angular Component Input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, template-literals

In my Angular 4 application, I have a component which takes a string input:

```
<app-my-component [myInput]="'some string value'"></app-my-component>
```

In some cases I need to pass a variable inside the string, for example:

```
<app-my-component [myInput]="'My name is ' + name + '!'"></app-my-component>
```

it would be nice if I could use [*es6 template literals*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (aka *template strings* or *back-tick strings*):

```
<app-my-component [myInput]="`My name is ${name}!`"></app-my-component>
```

but it doesn't work:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   Parser Error: Unexpected token Lexer Error: Unexpected character [`] at column 1 in expression

What's the correct way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

[*ES6 Template literals (Template strings)*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) cannot be used inside an Angular component input, because the [*Angular compiler*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/compiler) doesn't know this grammar.

The way that you provided is fine.

```js
<app-my-component [myInput]="'My name is ' + name + '!'"></app-my-component>
```

Or something like this,

In the component,

```js
// In the component, you can use ES6 template literal
name: string;
input: string;
    
ngOnInit() {
  this.name = 'Dinindu';
  this.input = `My name is ${this.name}!`;
}
```

In the HTML,

```js
<app-my-component [myInput]="input"></app-my-component>
```

Also can use it as this way. Its really close to template literal,

```js
<app-my-component myInput="My name is {{name}}"></app-my-component>
```

Comment: Is it still the case? What's the reason for that? I find it very strange that in 2020 it's still not supported.

Comment: Because it would not work with inline templates - this request has been rejected by Angular team - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12914

Comment: Still not working in 2023. Just works in vuejs though ;)

Answer (score 34):

You can still use angular's interpolation syntax in attribute values:

```
myInput="My name is {{ name }}!"
```

It's up to you which you prefer to write, but unfortunately backticks are not allowed in binding expressions.

Comment: Thank you, may I know why backticks are not allowed

Comment: Because it would not work with inline templates - this request has been rejected by Angular team - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12914

Comment: you can't use the template literal inside {{ }}

Answer (score 0):

Using a template literal expression works as long as the template lives in the TS source and not in HTML. So the below does NOT work

```html
<app-my-component [myInput]="`My name is ${name}!`"></app-my-component>
```

But the below WILL work

```js
let displayString: String = 'I work in a string literal - ';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-alerts',
  template: `
    ${displayString} Tada !!
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./product-alerts.component.css']
})
```

If you want to explore live code here is a sample:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qpxkbd-urdema?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproduct-alerts%2Fproduct-alerts.component.ts

Comment: This only works for very simple things. Something like `template: \`<ul>${['banana', 'apple'].map(fruit=>\`<li>${fruit}</li>\`).join('')}</ul>\`` will fail.